# ADVISE: Accessing PHP Objects in Internet Explorer from Excel VBA

Tags: php, vba, excel

I am trying to automate an excel upload process we have into our data warehouse. From Excel VBA, I am initiating an IE session to our data warehouse > login with my credentials > then navigate to the page to upload, but this is where I am having my problems.

The URL does not change when navigating this website, it is coded in PHP I believe. Therefore, I need to click the specific image - but I do not know how.

In my code below, I added my comments and the error message I receive when debugging. I also added an image of the website, the button I am trying to hit, and inspect of the element. Please help and thank you all in advance! <3 to Stack Overflow!

Signed, Doug Fresh

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement
Dim ele As Object
Dim y As Integer
Dim result As String

Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate "http://kpionline.bitam.com/english/memberlogin.php"
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
objIE.document.getElementById("user_name").Value = "username@bimbo.com" 'not real
objIE.document.getElementById("user_pwd").Value = "Bimbo2017" 'not real
objIE.document.getElementById("Login").Click
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
objIE.navigate "https://kpionline7.bitam.com/artus/genvi_test/LoadStage.php?txtRepositorio=fbm_bmd_0030&txtUser=xxxxxxx&txtPassword=xxxxx"
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

'**************************************************************************
'How do I click this icon???

    objIE.document.getElementById("ENL8").getElementsByTagName("img")(0).Click
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

'Please see image for php/js website code
'ERROR: Run-time error '424': Object required
'**************************************************************************

objIE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you place a break point on the line that should click the image? Then place a watch on everything on that line except `.Click` and see if its scoping the right object.

Answer (score 0):

try `objIE.document.getElementById("ENL8").Click`